# Cordova/Phonegap select box not opening on soft touch on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i created a cordova/phonegap app and i got few select elements, when i click on the selectbox i see the native select option pops and immidiatly closed, when i hold a long touch on the element it open correctly, the problem happened only on few devices and not all
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after alot of testing i finaly got the answer i was looking for.
it looks like the problem was in the cordova plugin called StatusBar at that link 
[Cordova StatusBar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

it seems like when that plugin attached to the android build it causing issues with Selectbox in some specific android versions. i did not really do test in what versions it happened exactly but after i removed it from my code everything worked smooth.

I hope it will help someone